# Use LEFT OUTER JOIN to include NULL values in query

Tags: sql, null, left-join, outer-join

I want the final query to include manufacturer_id | manufacturer_name | ice_cream_id | ice_cream_name so that the print includes also those manufacturer_names, which are included in the database but do not have any ice creams (NULL ice_cream_names). Then I want the results in ascending order by manufacturer.manufacturer_id, ice_cream.ice_cream_id which i already managed to do.

Here is my sample code and sample header of the dataset I deal with:

```
SELECT manufacturer.manufacturer_id, manufacturer.manufacturer_name, ice_cream.ice_cream_id, ice_cream.ice_cream_name
FROM ice_cream LEFT OUTER JOIN manufacturer
ON ice_cream.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.manufacturer_id OR manufacturer.manufacturer_name IS NULL 
ORDER BY manufacturer.manufacturer_id, ice_cream.ice_cream_id ASC;


manufacturer
manufacturer_id  manufacturer_name  country
---------------  -----------------  ----------
1                Jen & Berry        Canada
2                4 Friends          Finland
3                Gelatron           Italy

ice_cream
ice_cream_id  ice_cream_name    manufacturer_id  manufacturing_cost
------------  ----------------  ---------------  ------------------
1             Plain Vanilla     1                1
2             Vegan Vanilla     2                0.89
3             Super Strawberry  2                1.44
4             Very plain        2                1.2



ingredient
ingredient_id  ingredient_name  kcal        protein     plant_based
-------------  ---------------  ----------  ----------  -----------
1              Cream            400         3           0
2              Coconut cream    230         2.3         1
3              Sugar            387         0           1
4              Vanilla extract  12          0           1
5              Strawberry       33          0.7         1
6              Dark chocolate   535         8           1


contains
ice_cream_id  ingredient_id  quantity
------------  -------------  ----------
1             1              70
1             3              27
1             4              3
2             2              74
2             3              21
2             4              5
3             1              60
3             3              10
3             5              30
4             2              95
4             4              5
```

I wonder what's the logic between FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table 2; Are those in right order? And I think I do something extra in the "ON" stage that should be done in WHERE?

Comment: You only outer join on the related ID values, you don't need the `or` condition. What is the relevance to `ingredients` or `contains` tables to your question? Expected results would add clarity.

Comment: What is your question? What does "the logic between" mean? [mre]] [ask]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You want to keep all *manufacturers* according to your description.  Hence, that table should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.  I would also suggest using table aliases:

```
SELECT m.manufacturer_id, m.manufacturer_name, i.ice_cream_id, i.ice_cream_name
FROM manufacturer m LEFT JOIN
     ice_cream ic
     ON ic.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id 
ORDER BY m.manufacturer_id, ic.ice_cream_id ASC;
```

This doesn't require any fiddling with the `ON` clause, just proper use of the `LEFT JOIN`.